# blocking timer in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am currently using this 'timer code' in a windows service:

```
var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Timer = new Timer(DoWork, autoEvent, 0, TimeInMilliSeconds);
```

I am just wondering whether it would be possible to prevent the invocation of DoWork, if DoWork has not finished yet? In other words, if TimeInMilliSeconds is shorter than the time it takes to execute DoWork?

Comment: Well, you could avoid using a timer and instead block

Comment: Can you not simply add a global variable, say `isRunning` and check it in DoWork?

Comment: @David - I am always happy to learn - could you please provide an example?

Comment: @Yahya - an example would be nice too.

Comment: In a thread, you'd call `WaitOne` on a cancellation `EventWaitHandle` passing a timout to `WaitOne`. The timeout would be the amount of time you wish to wait before you next want to do work. This works if your thread is dedicated to doing this particular task, and nothing more. If you want to interleave other tasks, then that pushes you back to a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you can prevent the automatic callback and change the timer once when you need.

```
Timer = new Timer(DoWork, autoEvent, 0, Timeout.Infinite);//Prevent periodic timer

void DoWork(object state)
{
    //Do work and then set timer again
    timer.Change(TimeInMilliSeconds, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Don't forget to add `try/finally` block, if you don't do your timer will not be called again in case of exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand you code it would constantly invoke DoWork and execute DoWork as long as it takes is this correct?

Comment: I guess one could put a Sleep before timer.Change to have a 'slow' heartbeat if there is no work ...

Comment: No; it will invoke `DoWork` after completeing `DoWork` (whatever time it takes) it will set timer with `TimeInMilliSeconds`. That means it will wait `TimeInMilliSeconds` after each `DoWork`

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using a timer altogether.  In my program, I set the stop and pause events in the OnStop and OnPause methods.  They are cleared in the OnStart and OnContinue methods.  In this example I wait 30 seconds between trips through the loop.

```
 WaitHandle[] waitFor = new WaitHandle[]{stopEvent, pauseEvent};
 int trigger = -1;
 bool keepGoing = true;
 while(keepGoing)
 {
     trigger = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitFor, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
     switch (trigger) {
         case WaitHandle.WaitTimeout:
            The main body of the loop goes here
            break;
         case 0: // stop
             keepGoing = false;
             break;
         case 1: // pause
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Paused - ");
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
             break;
     }
```

*Edit*
As noted in another poster's comment, this is required to be in a thread separate from your main service.  Otherwise you will never process the stop, pause or resume events.

Comment: Thanks but I have to use a timer. Interesting approach though.